# Passing by reference makes a copy?

Tags: c++, methods, reference

Take for example two classes `A` and `B` where `B` is derived from `A`. If I implement a method using `A` such as:

```
void sum(A &val)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Then if I call `sum()` using an object of type `B` like so:

```
B b;
sum(b);
```

Does this create a temporary copy of `b`? Thank you!

Comment: Instead of describing some code, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no copy when passing by reference. The parameter is an alias for the argument. When the (called) function reads or writes the parameter, it actually reads or writes the argument itself. Which in your case is the `b` object itself.

Answer (score 1):

> If b is an instance of B, if I call sum(b) does a temporary copy of b is made?

Nope, it would just refer to the location of `b` in memory.